# Physical mac address on ESXi 3.5

Tags: vmware, esxi

I I'm new with vmware esxi 3.5 , someone know how see the physical mac address (NOT virtual) of  my network adapter. And if the Management Network mac addres IS the physical mac?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about the mac of a guest or of the ESXI box itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Virtual Infrastructure (VI) Client to go to and view the "Configuration" of the ESXi host. Then there is an option to view the "Network Adapters" which will show you the MAC addresses of the individual NICs.

The VI Client can be downloaded from VMware (http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/datacenter_downloads/vmware_infrastructure_3/3_5) or the web interface of the ESXi server.